# Stripping HTML tags with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/axfsD/1/

I'm trying to strip HTML tags in my pages.
I pasted below also two examples. By using **replace** command i can't strip first button's tags, but i can't strip second one's tags.
What can be the problem?

```
< script >
    $('button').replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
< /script>​

<button class="btn btn-info" rel="popover" data-content="hic   
aslinda sen de olabilir " data-original-title="Gemlik Bursa">
<small><span title="">mihan tosun</span></small></button>

<button class="btn btn-info" rel="popover" 
data-content="Benim olan benimdir Baskasinda gorduysen bil ki vazgecmisimdir   " 
data-original-title=""> <small><span title="">
Senin TAMER</span></small></button>​​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because replace() is a native JS function, not a jQuery one. So it won't repeat on all buttons. This is another way to do it that is more robust.

```
$('button').each(function(){
    var buttonText = $(this).text();
    $(this).empty().text(buttonText);
});
```

Comment: Why the useless `empty()` call? :-)

Comment: The empty call will remove the <span> and <small> tags.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to do this? perhaps `$.text()` [[Link to doc](http://api.jquery.com/text/)] does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex with HTML. Seriously, [just don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/851498).

If you want just the text, use the `text()` method. From what I understand, this is what you want:

```
$( 'button' ).each( function( index, value ) {
    $( this ).html = $( this ).text()
} )
```

Comment: Will this cause problems if the text contains characters that aren't encoded, like & <> "" etc...?

Comment: Why should it cause any problem?

Comment: Because then you'd end up setting the HTML to un-encoded characters which would break validation at least, at worst break the page layout.

Comment: There is not this kind of problem. If the text contains encoded characters in HTML, they're already encoded, so what's the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, looking into .text() it appears that it escapes characters anyway.

Comment: This thing also confused me. I would understand the error if there was a character to be escaped. But there exist no.

Comment: How can i use "text" in a backend javascript. I mean when not reading the DOM just making some parsing in the background by using buton's HTML code.  var output = $.text(buttonHtml) ?

Comment: Learn jQuery basics. It's `$(buttonHtml).text()` you're looking for, but I'm not even sure.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use html tags inside a button. If you need to change the button text's appearance, you can use css. Then you can grab the button's value using the .html() jquery function.